# why geoip not works for me

Tags: php, centos

I am trying to working with geoip to display Ips and their Countries  . I am trying to display this code but nothing comes up?

```
$country = geoip_country_name_by_name($ip);
```

Comment: "nothing comes up" -- what do you mean by that? What is the value of `$country` and do you use it anywhere to display it?

Comment: @rickdenhaan  he has a fatal error but his error reporting is off.
but still thats a wild guess only.

Comment: A little bit of your code in the post would go a long way to avoid all the `clarification` comments. **[Read all about a minimal, complete, verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.  People expect to see what you tried (your code), in a well formatted question. Help them help you. Please take the [**stack overflow tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know more about this site, and read about **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the GeoIP functions installed first. If they are installed, then it could be possible, that the IP you're providing to the function does not exist in the database.

Try this code:

```
<?php

$country = geoip_country_name_by_name($ip);
if ($country) {
    echo 'This host is located in: ' . $country;
} else {
    echo 'Cannot find the IP in the database.'
}
```